# How to reconcile the lyrics of "All is Found" with the events in Frozen 2?

Tags: frozen-ii

[According to the Frozen II's co-director Jennifer Lee](https://screenrant.com/frozen-2-disney-elsa-voice-mother-iduna-confirmed/), the voice that Elsa hears throughout the movie is her mother's voice. I am having a hard time reconciling this with the lyrics of the song "All is Found", which is the lullaby that is sung by Elsa and Anna's mother at the beginning of the movie (emphasis mine):

> Where the north wind meets the sea
> there's a river full of memory.
> Sleep, my darling, safe and sound
> for in this river all is found
>
> In her waters, deep and true
> lie the answers and a path for you.
> Dive down deep into her sound
> but not too far or you'll be drowned
>
> Yes, **she will sing to those who'll hear**
> and in her song, all magic flows,
> but can you brave what you most fear?
> Can you face what the river knows?
>
> Where the north wind meets the sea
> **there's a mother full of memory.
> Come, my darling, homeward bound**
> when all is lost, then all is found.

We are told that this lullaby is passed down amongst all the Northuldra (and in fact we see Elsa and one Northuldra woman sing a line together later in the movie), so this song is clearly old.  However, the song is referencing events of the movie specifically that as far as I can see can only happen till after Elsa's mother passes, specifically that her mother sings to her and resides in Ahtohallan.

This seems like a time paradox to me. Is there a plot point that I have overlooked that allows this to make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The world of Frozen is one of prophecy and magic. Per the back cover of the film novelisation;

> **When a prophecy traps a kingdom in eternal winter,** Anna, a young
> dreamer, must team up with Kristoff, a daring mountain man, and his
> reindeer on the grandest of journeys to find Anna's sister, the Snow
> Queen Elsa, and put an end to her icy spell. Encountering mystical
> trolls, a hilarious snowman named Olaf, Everest-like extremes, and
> magic at every turn, Anna and Kristoff battle the elements in a race
> to save the kingdom from destruction.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rear cover: Frozen - Official Novelisation](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Frozen_books)</sup></sub>

Pabbie attempts to foretell the future in scene in Frozen 2. He fails, but this clearly was an unexpected outcome.

> 

He discusses a similar feat (while hanging around with Agnarr and Iduna) in one of the Frozen tie-in novels.

> Grand Pabbie nodded. “She did. She knew we had the ability to help her
> forget. And forgetting was the only way she could live with what she’d
> done. She wanted to forget who she was. Who she’d left behind.” He
> paused, then added, **“But before we performed the spell, she had one
> other request. To see her son, not as he was then, but as he would
> be.” Grand Pabbie’s eyes zeroed in on Agnarr. “So we searched the
> Northern Lights for visions of your future. It is how I knew you would
> come to us someday.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Frozen 2: Dangerous Visions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_2:_Dangerous_Secrets)</sup></sub>

---

Note also that [an earlier version of the original Frozen film](https://ew.com/movies/2017/03/29/frozen-original-ending/) also had an "*[ancient troll prophecy](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Spring_Pageant)*" that appeared in song form.

> Your future is bleak
> Your kingdom will splinter
> Your land shall be cursed
> With unending winter
> With blasts of cold
> will come dark art,
> And a ruler
> With a frozen heart!
> Then all will perish in snow and ice!
> Unless you are freed with a sword sacrifice!

The ruler with a frozen heart turning out to be Hans, not Elsa.

Comment: Just to make sure I am on the same page - the idea is the song is not telling a story of how things are, but are rather a prophesy? Despite the present tense?

Comment: @SethMMorton - Sure. There are all sorts of songs in Frozen that are vaguely prophetic; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TXc2JbCjmw. It would appear that the trolls are masters of foretelling the future, so there's no good reason why these prognostications wouldn't be incorporated into songs and lullabies.